# NPM is changing the module name on install a local module

Tags: node.js, npm

I installed a local module using:

```
npm install --save file:./local-modules/public/node-mymodule
```

and NPM added this to package.json:

```
"mymodule": "file:./local-modules/public/node-mymodule"
```

How do I get NPM to not change the name.  I want to keep "node-mymodule" as the name.  After the installation, I manually changed the name in package.json to "node-mymodule" and updated the require statements.  Then I started the app but node couldn't find the module. I don't know if I'm running into a naming convention problem or something else.  I have seen other modules that start with "node-"

Comment: What does the original package.json look like? For the module that is

Comment: @James_Parsons, before the install, package.json has no reference to my module.  It's just a basic package.json with other dependencies.  After running the command above, NPM adds the dependency in the second block above to the "dependencies" section

Comment: No, I mean the package.json for **your module**

Comment: You might need to change the package name in package.json **within** the local module directory

Comment: @James_Parsons & fardjad, you're right, node-mymodule didn't have the "node-" part in it's package.json name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to make sure that the local module's name in its own package.json matched the main package.json dependency name.